# SPF record getting soft failed due to dynamic ip

Tags: spf

The SPF soft fail error I'm getting is:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning noreply@example.com
does not designate 64.202.189.129 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.202.189.129;
```

Issue is, the client ip mentioned above is changing in every email I receive even though I use SMTP relay from my server.

I talked with GoDaddy support & they said, ip will always change. There is no way it can use static ip for sending email.

What can be the possible solution to this? Can anybody help?

**EDIT**

I'm using VPS.

Comment: The best solution is: Don't use GoDaddy.

Comment: :D, any other solution? I just can't move away in a day, I paid rental of next three months already

Comment: The IP address in your server is dynamic? I understood correctly?

Comment: Nope ip address of my server is static, however emails are going from dynamic ip as per GoDaddy support.

Answer (score -4):

I used this configuration "v=spf1 a:smtp.example.com ~all" and it seems to work

If you used smtp of course